# Is Pensieve a pun?

Tags: harry-potter, pensieve

I'm sure that there's a word in the English language that's close to "pensieve" that means something like "contemplative" or "in deep thought". Do we know anything about the origin of the term? I feel like I'm missing a pun.

Comment: [Pensive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pensive) (adj) - musingly or dreamily thoughtful

Comment: Not so much a pun as Ms. Rowling trying to be clever.

Comment: @JRE Rowling try to be clever with wordplay while naming things?  Surely you jest

Comment: As much you have to pay for a pensieve, if you want something that used to be a pensieve, that's really ex-pensieve.

Comment: french *penser* = "to think"

Comment: @JRE Going further than that, it's her trying to write a world where people name things in clever ways. In her world, some wizard invented the device and named it _pensieve_ because they thought it was clever. Her books often contrast the whimsy of how people think and behave in the wizarding world with the ordinary, boring "Muggle" world (and, in later books, how this can cause problems for both). For instance, she didn't make up a cleverly-named game console for Dudley, she used _PlayStation_. I'd say she _succeeded_ at being clever, she didn't just try, but that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Pensieve is also an anagram of Pevensie, the last name of the four children in Narnia.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, according to JKR it's intended as a pun.

> The name ‘Pensieve’ is a homonym of ‘pensive’, meaning deeply,
> seriously thoughtful; but it also a pun, the ‘sieve’ part of the word
> alluding to the object’s function of sorting meanings from a mass of
> thoughts or memories.
>
> <sub><sup>[Pensieve By J.K. Rowling - Pottermore](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pensieve)</sup></sub>

Comment: Well that's awkward. I'm pretty sure that my accent would have me pronounce both of those words exactly the same.

Comment: That's what homonyms are: words that are pronounced the same.

Comment: And homographs are spelled the same, although not all homographs are homonyms as anyone who has bowed with a bow in their hair knows. Sometimes, they're even [contranyms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_contranyms) that have opposite meanings.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron I though hom*nyms* were words that were *spelled* the same, but had different meanings (e.g. record: a list of historical notes, and record: a vinyl disk which holds music and audio), while words that *sound* the same are homo*phones* (e.g., to, too, and two)? But maybe the denotations have shifted meanings over the decades, or I just learned it wrong. :)

Comment: Yes, there are more specialized words that linguists need and logophiles delight in, but in plain English, a homonym is "each of two or more words having the same spelling or pronunciation but different meanings and origins."

Comment: Interesting to note that "Pen" means "Head" in Welsh (I don't know if JKR took that into account or not)

Comment: This is of course one of those jokes that is completely lost in the movies, because you never see it spelled.

Comment: It's additionally confusing as a homonym pun because the characters in the movie, especially Snape, pronounce 'Pensieve' totally differently than how 'pensive' is pronounced. He uses a ridiculously over-done French accent on the word so that it sounds like "Ponseeve", as I recall.

Comment: @Lexible Homo*phones* are words that sound the same, homo*graphs* are words that look the same, and homo*nyms* are a collective term for words which are either or both of those (i.e. "read" (past tense, as "red") and "read" (present tense, as "reed") are homographs and homonyms, but not homophones, "weight" and "wait" are homophones and homonyms, but not homographs, while "light" (photons and electromagnetic waves), "light" (pale, not dark) and "light" (not heavy) are all three)

Comment: @TylerH ...that's actually how I pronounce "sieve" anyway (in the US), and pensive/pensieve also end up different in the same way.

Comment: @Izkata In both US and UK English "sieve" is pronounced "siv" with a short `i` sound.

Comment: @J. Mini: As a US English speaker, I would have assumed the word would be pronounced with three syllables - pen-si-ev (with the final e being silent).

Comment: @TylerH Maybe he's trying to not cast a spell

Comment: @Chronocidal O nameless spirit of linguistics I *bow* before you. (Oh wait, you actually have a name. Carry on!)

Comment: I pronounce "sieve" as "siv" but "pensieve" as "pen-SEEV." No idea why, it just sounds weird to pronounce it exactly like "pensive", even though that's the pun.